# Inkscape: After combining paths, specify which one is inside and outside

Tags: inkscape

So, I am hand-tracing a logo in Inkscape, one of the letters is a B. My problem is, when I combine the 3 paths of the B and setting a fill color, Inkscape also fills the lower hole, which it shouldn't. What can I do to make inkscape treat my B like it should?

Comment: How have you combined the three paths? Have you used the [difference](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) operation?

Comment: I used the combine operation.

Comment: For such a shape, I'd use the difference: the B letter is a shape with two holes and you can obtain a hole using the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've combined all your paths into one, try this.

1. Go to the "Fill" tab of the "Fill and Stroke" dialog. At the top right of the Fill tab is "Fill rule". Set this to "evenodd" (the one on the left). I'm guessing this will do it.

Or, if your paths are still separate:

1. Select all paths
2. Choose "Path" > "Exclusion"